# SQL calculations not returning the expected values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've taken over a project from a different developer. This developer favoured working in SQL over C# code, however I am admittedly not very strong with SQL and am having trouble fixing a bug in the project.

A holiday system exists in this project. Each user has the following:

- Entitled holidays
- Holiday taken
- Lieu/adjusted holidays
- Holiday brought forward

A remaining holiday value is then calculated which takes the above values and generates a result.

For example, Person A has:

- 20 entitled
- 7.5 taken
- 3 in lieu
- 2 brought forward

The *expected* result would be 17.5 remaining ((20 + 3 + 2) - 7.5) however the result given from the existing stored procedure for the above example is 22

Another user has the following:

- 25 entitled
- 1 taken
- 2 in lieu
- 5 brought forward

This user is seeing 30 instead of the expected 31

Since each individual value for the above seems to working, it points to the calculation of the total remaining holiday that's not working. Here is the current procedure for calculating this value:

```
    DECLARE @USER_HOLIDAYS decimal(18,2) 
    DECLARE @LieuAdjustedHolidays decimal(18,2)
    DECLARE @Total_Holidays decimal(18,2) 
    DECLARE @Remain_Holidays decimal(18,2) 

    SELECT @USER_HOLIDAYS = SUM(HolidayEntitlement + HolidaysBroghtForward) 
    FROM cms_user        
    WHERE UserID = @UserID

    SELECT 
        @LieuAdjustedHolidays = CASE 
                                   WHEN SUM(Duration) IS NULL 
                                      THEN 0 
                                      ELSE SUM(Duration) 
                                END 
    FROM 
        No6_LieuAdjustedHolidays 
    WHERE 
        UserID = @UserID 
        AND ItemCreatedWhen >=  '' + CAST(DATEPART(yy,  GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' -11-01'

    SET @Total_Holidays = SUM(@USER_HOLIDAYS + CASE WHEN @LieuAdjustedHolidays IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @LieuAdjustedHolidays END )

    SELECT 
        @Remain_Holidays = @Total_Holidays - CASE WHEN SUM(Duration) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(Duration) END 
    FROM 
        No6_Holidays 
    WHERE 
        ItemCreatedby = @UserID 
        AND status = 'Accepted' 
        AND StartDate >=  '' + CAST(DATEPART(yy,  GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' -11-01'
        AND EndDate <= '' + CAST(DATEPART(yy,  DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(100)) + '-10-31'  

    UPDATE cms_user 
    SET RemainingHolidays = @Remain_Holidays 
    WHERE UserID = @UserID

    SELECT 
        @Total_Holidays  - CASE WHEN SUM(Duration) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(Duration) END 
    FROM 
        No6_Holidays 
    WHERE 
        ItemCreatedby = @UserID 
        AND status = 'Accepted' 
        AND StartDate >=  '' + CAST(DATEPART(yy,  GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' -11-01'
        AND EndDate <= '' + CAST(DATEPART(yy,  DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(100)) + '-10-31'
```

With this part being the section that I don't believe is calculating correctly:

```
SELECT @Total_Holidays  - CASE WHEN SUM(Duration) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(Duration) END FROM No6_Holidays 
        WHERE ItemCreatedby = @UserID and status = 'Accepted' and StartDate >=  '' + cast(DATEPART(yy,  GETDATE()) as varchar(100)) + ' -11-01'
        and EndDate <= '' + cast(DATEPART(yy,  DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE())) as varchar(100)) + '-10-31'
```

Since I have a very limited understanding of SQL I'm struggling to understand what's going wrong here. Is anyone able to help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nobody can help without some details. We need a lot more than just a bunch of code hitting unknown tables with unknown values. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: start from casting the dates at the where clause.

Comment: Debug this by putting a PRINT statement between each update/select clause and print your variable values. Then you should be able to tell which statement is going sideways.

Comment: thanks for this - I had no idea how to get the variable values for debugging!

Comment: `PRINT @Remail_Holidays`, `PRINT @User_Holidays`, ...

Comment: Unrelated to your question but the multi-line case expression `CASE WHEN SUM(Duration) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(Duration) END` could be replaced with `SUM(COALESCE(Duration, 0))` or `SUM(ISNULL(Duration, 0))`. The SQL Standard defines `COALESCE` while SQL Server also provides the non-standard `ISNULL`.